# wp8 PeriodicTask and persisted storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a PeriodicTask that updates a tile for my phone app and saves the information to persisted storage.

This works fine until the list gets to around a size of 11 or 12.

The objects that I save is a poco object with about 5 members.
I basiclly get data, save data and create tile (not shown).

so

```
//get data
var newData = GetPocoFromWeb();
base.Add(newData);
```

the base class

```
     public abstract class DataFetcher<T> where T : IDataCarrier, new()
        {
            protected readonly IPersist<List<T>> Persist;
            protected DataFetcher(IPersist<List<T>> persist)
            {
                Persist = persist;
            }

            protected void Add(T item)
            {
                var items = Persist.Load();
                items.Add(item);
                Persist.Save(items);
            }
        }
```

The persist class

```
public class Persist<T> : IPersist<T>
    {
        private readonly string _identifier;

        public Persist(string identifier)
        {
            _identifier = identifier;
        }

        public virtual T Load()
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(_identifier))
            {
                return (T)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[_identifier];
            }

            return default(T);
        }

        public virtual void Save(T item)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[_identifier] = item;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }  

    }
```

Am I perhaps using wrong storage? 
11 items in a list isn't really that many.

Update:
When I load the list and add to it using the application (not through the periodicTask) i can easily save several hundred items.

I don't get any error when running in emulator, it just works till the list has around 11 items and then stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't go into much detail into what error you are getting (if any), so it's difficult to say.

Having said that, here's a few things that come to mind:

- If you call `NotifyComplete()` before the asynchronous call *completes*, you may be being shut down before you have the chance
- Background tasks only have 6mb of memory (12mb on WP8). If you go over it your process will be terminated
- Background tasks only have 25 seconds or so to execute. If you continue past this your process will be terminated.
- [Don't use the `IsolatedStorageSettings` class to share state between processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_CommunicationBetweenForegroundApplicationandBackgroundAgent)
- You should be using a `Mutex` to protect process-process access to your storage.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect I might be popping over the memory limit and perhaps I have been going about this wrong.  
I read up on the isolatedstoragesettings and it seems that perhaps I might be better using a local db.

I'll test tonight and update with results

Comment: it was the memory, it seems i must have been on the verge due to how i create my tiles (controltoimage) and the isolated storage pushed it over the edge... funny i was so close though. I have reworked the image creation which gives me more memory to play with..

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem you're experiencing? Using IsolatedStorageSettings shouldn't restrict the size of the list you're able to persist.

Comment: I used isolated storage for the main app and it works (I tested up to about 150) the problem is that when running this technique with Periodtask the resources required fall out of microsoft requirements on a periodtask.
I find it weird that it fall out when the list size to save is only 11 big